# Are cent and cena related?

Tags: etymology

A number of Slavic languages have the word "cena" meaning "price":

Slovenian, Slovak, Polish ***cena***, Russian ***цена***

I wonder whether it is related to the word ***cent***

Comment: Wiktionary claims they derive from different paths back to different PIE roots.

Comment: Surely, Anixx, you are aware that "cent" is the French word for "one hundred". Where do you see a semantic connection?

Comment: Ok, cent is supposed to be the Latin not the French word for "100".

Answer (score 3):

Slavic *cena* comes from Proto-Balto-Slavic *kaina* (which is still *kaina* in Lithuanian). IIRC the word originally meant something like "penalty, punishment, retribution" (see Ancient Greek *ποινή* "penalty, redemption"; also *τίνω* "to pay a price, be punished").

English/French *cent* come from Latin *centum* (in the meaning "1/100 of something"), which comes from *ḱm̥tóm* "hundred".
So, English/French *cent* are actually related to Slavic *sto* "hundred".

Comment: Latin "centum" means "one hundred" not "one hundredth". The American English "cent" is probably a contraction of "centime".

Comment: See etymonline, it does stem from *centum*: "Middle English meaning was "one hundred," but it shifted 17c. to "hundredth part" under influence of percent". It's the other way around, French *centime* stems from *cent* on analogy of *décime*. I didn't mean that Latin *centum* itself means 1/100; I meant the English/French used it that way.

Comment: etymonline is not a reliable source. You can look it up in the OED where it is explained as in my comment.

Comment: In any case, *cent* ultimately stems from *centum*, and that's what matters ITT.

Comment: In France the usage of "centime" starts from the introduction of the decimal monetary system under Napoleon (before, it was non-decimal); meanwhile the earliest mention of "cent" in the US in the meaning of a currency is year 1782. I think confusion of "cent" with "per cent" makes a lot of sense, and easily explains OED's examples from 1600's (not-currency related) Centime in English is a borrowing from French (OED-confirmed), so it's a post 1800's word (OED-confirmed).